# Cache-control headers not added on azure linux app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config, cache-control

I host an angular frontend inside an Azure App Service on Linux. Stack is Node 12.
In order to enable the response headers "Cache-Control" for the static files I have added the line

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="3.00:00:00" />
```

inside the Web.config file as suggested in the microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content#using-webconfig-files)

The Web.config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <clear />
        <add
            name="StaticFile"
            path="*" verb="*"
            modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule"
            resourceType="Either"
            requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="3.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
     </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Unfortunately the headers are not set correctly. Is there something wrong with the Web.config file? Does the Azure App Service on Linux have to do something with it?

Comment: Doris's answer should be correct. For `PaaS` services, we can't do more settings. If the `.htaccess` is modified and the attempt is invalid, the hard code can only be used to implement `cache-control` every time a request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The `web.config` file is **only for IIS** configuration system, but IIS is not for Linux.

So you could **not** set the `cache-control` header in `web.config` file.

If you have entity instance for Linux, you could use **Apache `.htaccess`** file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

If you don't have entity instance for Linux, you could set the header **in code**:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

I have tried using .htaccess file on Azure, but it did not work as Azure is a PaaS, which did not include a entity instance.