# PWA Caching Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, azure-web-app-service, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA which has been developed in ASP.net Core and hosted on an Azure App Service (Linux).

When a new version of the PWA was released, I found that devices failed to update without clearing the browser cache.

To resolve this, I discovered a tag helper called **asp-append-version** that will clear cache for a specific file. I also discovered that I can append the version of the src attribute that specifies the URL of a file to trigger the browser to retrieve the latest file. For example, src="/scripts/pwa.js?**v=1**". Each time I update the pwa.js file I would also change the version i.e. **v=2**.

I’ve now discovered that my PWA is caching other JavaScript files in my application which results in the app not working on devices that have been updated to the new version however failed to clear the cache on specific files.

I believed that if I didn’t specify any cache control headers such as Cache-Control that the browser would not cache any files however this appears not to be the case.

To resolve this issue, is the recommended approach to add the appropriate Cache-Control headers *(Cache-Control, Pragma, and Expires)* to prevent browser caching or should I only add the tag helper **asp-append-version** to for example scripts tags to auto clear cache for that specific file?

I would preferably like the browser to store for example images rather than going to the server each time to retrieve these. I believe setting the header **Cache-Control: no-cache** would work as this would check if the file has changed before retrieving the updated version?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ [SteveSandersonMS](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS) for your insights, In your web server returns correct HTTP cache control headers, browsers will know not to re-use cached resources.

Refer here [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814607/cache-control-headers-not-added-on-azure-linux-app-service) & [link 2](https://www.koskila.net/enable-local-cache-for-azure-app-service/) for Cache control headers on `Linux app service`

For example, if you use the "ASP.NET Core hosted" version of the Blazor WebAssembly template, the server will return `Cache-Control: no-cache` headers which means the browser will always check with the server whether updated content is present (and this uses etags, so the server will return 304 meaning "keep using your cached content" if nothing has changed since the browser last updated its content).

If you use a different web server or service, you need to configure the web server to return correct caching headers. Blazor WebAssembly can't control or even influence that.

Refer [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20408)